# htaccess url rewrite without loosing url parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have created a htaccess url rewrite to geht my urls webseite.com/dashboard.php to webseite.com/dashboard.

My Problem is, that I am giving parameters (for database data) over my url when I visit certain sites of my website like `https://example.com/detail_user.php?id=1`.

With my rewrite rules it ignores the parameters added to the url.

Is there any htaccess rule to give parameters to an url but when visiting the normal site remove the .php ending?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
```

Comment: The default behavior is to append the specified query string when you rewrite a URL. Which is what you ask for. So the question is why it does _not_ work in your case. Could you please add a specific URL you request to the question?

Comment: "i have created a htaccess url rewrite to geht my urls webseite.com/dashboard.php to webseite.com/dashboard" - The rule you've posted does not do that (it does the opposite). Please post your complete `.htaccess` file, as the problem would seem to be _somewhere else_.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to append [QSA].

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [QSA]
```

QSA means "Query String Append", if there's a query string passed with the original URL, it will be appended to the rewrite.

In your use case, `/detail_user.php?id=1` becomes `/detail_user?id=1`

Comment: You may also want to add [L, QSA], L means it will be the last/final rule it will run.

Comment: There should be no _space_ in the _flags_ argument (that would result in a 500 error). However, the `QSA` flag is not the issue here. The original query string is appended by default when no query string is stated in the _substitution_ string.

Answer (score -1):

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)?$ $1.php?$2

Comment: Answers should not consist of code lines only, they should always contain an explanation. They should be written with proper formatting. And they should answer the actual question asked, not something along the topic.